# Angular tooltip getting out of the viewport

Tags: javascript, angular, tooltip

I have a dynamically generated tooltip where width and content is provided to the component using @Input. However, I am not able to find a way to set the position of the tooltip so that it stays inside the view port but not over the content. Whenever the hoverable content is at the edge of the viewport like top/ bottom/ left / right than the tooltip doesn't shows up inside the viewport.

I know that I have to calculate the position of the hovered element using getBoundingClientRect(), but how do I set the position in such a way that the tooltip doesn't overlap the hovered content.

Here is my code :

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="background:red;">
<p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
  PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu
</p>

<button awesomeTooltip="Hello World!"  image="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">Hi there, check for a tooltip</button>
</div>
```

**tooltip.component.html**

```
   <img [src]="image" width= "300px" @tooltip>
```

**tooltip.directive.ts**

```
import { ComponentRef, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Overlay, OverlayPositionBuilder, OverlayRef } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { ComponentPortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

import { AwesomeTooltipComponent } from './tooltip.component';

@Directive({ selector: '[awesomeTooltip]' })
export class AwesomeTooltipDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('awesomeTooltip') text = '';
  @Input('image') image = '';
  private overlayRef: OverlayRef;

  constructor(private overlay: Overlay,
              private overlayPositionBuilder: OverlayPositionBuilder,
              private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const positionStrategy = this.overlayPositionBuilder
      .flexibleConnectedTo(this.elementRef)
      .withPositions([{
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'top',
        overlayX: 'center',
        overlayY: 'bottom',
        offsetY: -8,
      }]);

    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({ positionStrategy });
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  show() {
    const tooltipRef: ComponentRef<AwesomeTooltipComponent>
      = this.overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(AwesomeTooltipComponent));
    tooltipRef.instance.text = this.text;
    tooltipRef.instance.image = this.image;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout')
  hide() {
    this.overlayRef.detach();
  }
}
```

Stackblitz link is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9py6n?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip%2Ftooltip.directive.ts)

The result I am looking is that the tooltip should be inside the viewport whenever it is getting out.

Comment: May be https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tooltip-directive would help.

Comment: But it has hard coded position entered. can't it be done more programatically